# Problems adding Apache Spark to Eclipse Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop, apache-spark

I am attempting to add Apache Spark MLlib as a dependency for a Maven project in Eclipse.  I have the Maven plugin, so adding dependencies is usually as easy as entering in the address (don't even have to touch the pom.xml). When I tried to add MLlib, I got the error:

"Archive for the required library (location of spark-core jar) cannot be read or is not a valid zip file"

So I went and added that jar as a dependency as well, but the error continued to happen, just with different jars (hadoop was next, then snappy-java, etc) with more and more dependencies needing to be added.  Eventually, I seemed to have added all the required dependencies, but the error just looped back to the hadoop one:

"Archive for the required library (location of hadoop jar) cannot be read...."

When I tried to remove and re-add these, it just continued to loop through all of them again.  I 'm pretty new to Maven so maybe I'm missing something major, but I am very confused.

Comment: Come on guys, this seems like a reasonable question - thus kinda harsh to downvote.

Answer (score 2):

You have not shared your `pom.xml` file and it seems you do not want to edit it. Anyhow, make sure in order to use MLlib you must have following dependency added to your application's `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```